# How to set background across this bar

Tags: html, css, background, nav

I am trying to set the background to go horizontally across this bar to be behind the logo and nav

Here is the HTML

```
<!--NAV-->
<div class="header">
    <div class="title">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
    </div><!--/.title-->
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
.title
{
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.nav
{
  font-size:20px;
  color:#0F3;
  display:inline;
  float:right;
  margin:0 1.7%;
  padding:1% 4% 0;
}

ul
{
  display:inline;
  float:right;
  list-style:none;
}

li
{
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: where did you put the background css???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify `.header` class.

Keep in mind that floating divs don't affect the size of the surrounding element. So you can use `overflow: auto;` in header class to make the surrounding element take the floating elements in consideration:

Example

```css
.header {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/100/abstract/);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto; 
}
img {
  padding: 12px;
}
.title {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 1.7%;
  padding: 0 4%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
ul {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/40/people/">
  </div>
  <!--/.title-->
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. So if i wanted to use the same format for a footer. But raise the height of it. How would i do that?

Comment: @JonyTalassazan read http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: @JonyTalassazan be sure to accept an answer if you think your question has been answered.